# Swift guard statement pattern matching with enum

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I'm trying to return the head element of my own implementation of a Doubly Linked List in Swift.
My Nodes are declared as an enum like this:

```
enum DLLNode<Element>{
    indirect case Head(element: Element, next: DLLNode<Element>)
    indirect case Node(prev: DLLNode<Element>, element: Element, next: DLLNode<Element>)
    indirect case Tail(prev: DLLNode<Element>, element: Element)
}
```

and the list implementation like this:

```
struct DLList<Element> {
    var head:DLLNode<Element>?

...

func getFirst()throws->Element{
        if self.isEmpty(){
            throw ListError.EmptyList(msg: "")
        }
        guard case let DLLNode<Element>.Head(element: e, next: _) = head
            else{
                throw ListError.UnknownError(msg: "")
        }
        return e
    }
}
```

But I'm getting `"Invalid pattern"` on the guard statement. If I omit the `DLLNode<Element>` and just keep it like `guard case let .Head(element: e, next: _) = head` it gives me `"Enum case 'Head' not found in 'guard case let DLLNode<Element>.Head(element: e, next: _) = head'"`
What am I doing wrong? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two problems:

- You must not repeat the generic placeholder `<Element>` in the pattern.
- `head` is an *optional*, so you have to match it against
  `.Some(...)`.

Therefore:

```
guard case let .Some(.Head(element: e, next: _)) = head
```

or, using the equivalent `x?` pattern:

```
guard case let .Head(element: e, next: _)? = head
```